# Moving datadir OK start, but socket error for mysql client

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, centos, datadir

I'm trying to move my MySQL datadir from /var/lib/mysql over to /home/mysql (an ssd drive as I'm having iowait issues on /var/lib/mysql when MySQL is running on that drive).

The OS is CentOS 5.6 (final), MySQL version is 5.5.17-log and Selinux is disabled.

---

I've read many how-tos on the web and here is the procedure I'm using:

1. mkdir /home/mysql  and then chown mysql:mysql /home/mysql
2. flush tables;
3. service mysqld stop
4. cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql/* /home/mysql/
5. mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_off
6. in my.cnf change datadir=/home/mysql   and change socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
7. service mysqld start (it starts fine,OK)

---

When I go to load my website (or any other sites on this same server) I get this error:

```
error sql: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

So it's clearly trying to access the old socket location which is invalid since I'm changing the MySQL directory to mysql_old.

The mysql error log does not show any issues when i start up and does show the new socket location, with no errors (see bottom for the mysql error log)

Solutions I've tried: adding to my.cnf:

```
[client]
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and then starting mysqld -> same error.

---

I know I can just make a sym link of /var/lib/mysql -> /home/mysql and that will solve this but I want to know why I'm getting that error even with the [client] socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock  and how to fix this so that I don't have to make a symlink.

---

Other info:

ls -la of actual /home/mysql:

```
drwxr-xr-x 26 mysql      mysql           4096 Aug 16 21:40 mysql
```

ls -la of actual /var/lib/mysql:

```
drwxr-xr-x 26 mysql     mysql   4096 Aug 16 21:41 mysql

[root@x home]# sestatus -v 
<p>SELinux status: disabled
```

mysqld error log with socket and data dir set to my new locations: /home/mysql/:

```
140816 21:39:36 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140816 21:39:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /home/mysql
140816 21:39:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140816 21:39:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140816 21:39:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140816 21:39:56 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 784856558
140816 21:39:56 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@xxx.xxxx.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140816 21:39:56 [Warning] 'user' entry '@xxxx.xxxx.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140816 21:39:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140816 21:39:56 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.17-log'  socket: '/home/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

---

mysqld error log prior with socket and data dir set to: /var/lib/mysql:

```
140816 21:40:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140816 21:40:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140816 21:40:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140816 21:40:59 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140816 21:40:59  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140816 21:41:00 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 784856558
140816 21:41:00 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@xxxx.xxxx.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140816 21:41:00 [Warning] 'user' entry '@xxx.xxxx.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140816 21:41:00 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140816 21:41:00 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.17-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

Comment: Please include the result of shell> selinuxenabled && echo "yes!"

Comment: I should have included that selinux is not enabled (its disabled): 
[root@x home]# sestatus -v
SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: @James Gaul first thing first, what do you get when you run "mysql" the command line client with the configured parameters with a non-root user, can you log in? (check that /home/mysql/mysql.sock is accessible for non-root users)

Comment: Thanks jynus,  im getting the same socket error when i log in non root into mysql via CLI,  the web site (php that access mysql) that i copied and pasted the sock error code from does not use root to access the DB but its own user/password.  ive added the mysql error log for both start ups and there are no errors/differences in the log, and each startup error log notes the proper sock file location (and no error)

Comment: Then your problem is on mysql client configuration, check that you have mysql.sock with the right permissions: in my case: `$ mysql --socket=mysql.sock 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'mysql.sock' (13)
$ sudo chmod o+w mysql.sock 
$ mysql --socket=mysql.sock 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.` Other things that could go wrong: `skip-networking` not recognizing localhost for authentication and client configuration not being used: check with `mysql --print-defaults`.

Comment: Thanks so much, i think one of those two options is my exact issue!  however, when i shutdown mysqld before i do the copy of the data directory from /var/lib/mysql to /home/mysql (my new directory) it closes/removes the mysql.sock file so when i do the copy there is no mysql.sock file at the new location to do chmod o+w mysql.sock (if i try it on my new data directory, I get 'mysql.sock' no such file or directory).  -- as for mysql --print-defaults the result i get is: 'mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--user=root --pass=NOT_MY_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD (some other pass)

Comment: Do not worry about the socket disappearing! :-) That is normal, but if you restart and the configuration has been done properly, it will appear on the new location after start (created by the MySQL server). The client is not seeing the configuration change, make sure you have edited correctly your `[client]` section on your `my.cnf`. In summary, you must stop the server, change your `socket` configuration on both `[mysqld]` and `[client]` and start again, in that order.

Comment: Your websites might not use `[client]` section to find the unix socket. They may have their own configuration, potentially not in this file at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution, but having the same issue, setting the protocol to tcp in `my.cnf`, I was able to workaround the issue like this:

```
[client]
# avoid using mysql.sock
protocol=tcp
```

Alternatively, you can specify it when running the mysql client `mysql -u username -p --host=127.0.0.1`

As per https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31577

Note, the above solutions as suggested in the comments did not work for me.